# Java - If-Else - inaccessible inside-object declaration

Tags: java, class, object, if-statement

```
public class RunProg {
    static int input1; //for creating new human;
    static boolean Married; //for knowing if married or not
    static String isMarried; //for the YES or No of Married Boolean

public static void main(String[] args) {


    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


    System.out.print("What would you like to do? \n 1-Create new Human?\n");
    input1 = input.nextInt();
    input.nextLine();

    //Inputs for The NEW HUMAN
    if (input1 == 1) {
        System.out.println("Enter name:");
        String Name = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Good! Now enter the age of " + Name + ": ");
        int Age = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Well done! Now enter length: ");
        int Length = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Finally, is he/she married? ('YES' or 'NO') ");
        isMarried = input.nextLine();


        if (isMarried == "YES") {
            Married = true;
            Human h1 = new Human(Name, Age, Length, Married);
        }

         else if (isMarried == "NO") {
            Married = false;
            Human h1 = new Human(Name, Age, Length);
        }

    }
```

How can I modify this code to make `h1` accessible inside and outside if-else 
without declaring it outside if-else?
This is addressing the problem of the Objects' accessibility that is strictly scoped between the brackets of the if-else statement
I'm asking if there is a way of making the 'inside'accessible outside the brackets (I fully understand the scopes of variables; so please don't bother me with scopes,naming conventions and outer declarations)

Comment: Move it outside of it. It's scope is limited to the `{}` of the `if`.

Comment: Well his question was how to do it without moving it outside and I don't think that is possible

Comment: Exactly. You could declare it outside but instantiate inside, but you can't get around the scope issue.

Comment: this will break your code too: ***if (isMarried == "YES") {***

Comment: Have you heard about naming conventions (like JCC)? Static variables also aren't a good choice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What if-else block?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


    System.out.print("What would you like to do? \n 1-Create new Human?\n");
    input1 = input.nextInt();
    input.nextLine();

    //Inputs for The NEW HUMAN
    if (input1 == 1) {
        System.out.println("Enter name:");
        String Name = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Good! Now enter the age of " + Name + ": ");
        int Age = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Well done! Now enter length: ");
        int Length = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Finally, is he/she married? ('YES' or 'NO') ");
        isMarried = input.nextLine();

        Human h1 = new Human(Name, Age, Length, "YES".equals(isMarried));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to move the h1 declaration to the outer scope to access it there. Variables are block scoped. Then you'll just initialize the variable in the if block.

```
if (input1 == 1) {
    Human h1;
    ...     

    if ("YES".equals(isMarried)) {
        Married = true;
        h1 = new Human(Name, Age, Length, Married);
    }

     else if ("NO".equals(isMarried)) {
        Married = false;
        h1 = new Human(Name, Age, Length);
    }

}
```

Or Refactor to remove the If/Else block:

```
Human h1 = new Human(Name, Age, Length, "YES".equals(isMarried));
```

Edit: Switched to calling .equals on "YES" since it won't be null.

Comment: `"YES".equals(isMarried)` is a better way

Comment: There is certainly room for refactoring. I just addressed the specific concern.

Comment: and don't use `==` for `String` comparisons